# JSON object group by value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I created product database with JSON:

```
{
"1": {"group":"1", "name":"bmw" },
"2": {"group":"1", "name":"audi"},
"3": {"group":"2", "name":"volvo"}
}
```

But now I need to create an HTML drop down with all elements by group id.

I tried using Javascript `.grep()` but I don't have enough experience how to do that. Any help?

```
var all;
$.getJSON("data.json", function( data ) {
    all = data;
});
var group1 = $.grep(all, function(el, i) {
    return el.group. === 2
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(group1));
```

Comment: Show your attempt with grep and your desired output

Comment: This might be a good place to start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: didn't found anything helpful in my case

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) [`$.grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) is for use with arrays, *coincidentally* it also has several clear examples... your *JSON* object is ***not*** an array but an object literal.  Ideally instead of this:

```json
{
    "1": {"group":"1", "name":"bmw"  },
    "2": {"group":"1", "name":"audi" },
    "3": {"group":"2", "name":"volvo"}
}
```

Your response should be coming back similar to this:

```json
{
    products: [
        {"group":"1", "name":"bmw"  },
        {"group":"1", "name":"audi" },
        {"group":"2", "name":"volvo"}    
    ]
}
```

Then with a little tweaking your example will return the object's you desire in another array - take note of the difference between the [`===`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) and the [`==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) [operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) as in your *JSON* example the group is returned as a ***string*** as opposed to a ***number***.

```js
var group1 = $.grep(all.products, function(el, i){
    return el.group == 2;
});
```

---

If you still wish to work with your original *JSON* object (which you shouldn't as it's keys seem redundant and somewhat inefficient), then you will have to devise your own method of filtering.  *For example:*

```js
var group1 = {};
$.each(all, function(i, el){
    if(el.group == 2) group1[i] = el; 
});
```